# Problem on Setting up Oracle SQL Developer different error popping up

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to set up Oracle Database for an application that I am going to use, so I assume that I only need to set it up once.

I tried to set it up based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUpvXMHqe2U&ab_channel=GeekyScript and for the installation of Oracle 19c it works just fine. This is part of the setup:

[image: Oracle installer]

But I have a problem when I try to set up database connection on Oracle SQL Developer. When I tried to set it up like this, there is an error code ORA 12505:

[image: SQL Developer ORA-12505]

Many tutorials mentioned to look into the tnsnames.ora or listener.ora in network/admin folder:

[image: tnsnames.ora]

[image: listener.ora]

I tried to input many combination based on the data above in the SQL Developer, and got an error code ORA-01017 invalid username/password:

[image: SQL Developer ORA-01017]

So, I am not sure what did I do wrong, but with the same password I can get into SQL*Plus.

Comment: When you connect locally from SQL\*Plus (e.g. with `sys/xxx as sysdba`) it doesn't actually use the password, so even if you've used the same value it might not really be correct. Remember that it's case-sensitive, and check you're using the password you set for SYS not SYSTEM or any others. You could also connect through SQL\*Plus and change the SYS password if you aren't sure. (Also when posting here please include formatted text whenever you can, not images; e.g. for the contents of files.)

Comment: Hi! thanks soo much, I ended up changing up the sys and system password based on this link https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-change-sys-and-system-passwords-in-oracle-database/ what is exactly the password I entered when I open SQL*PLUS? and now that I changed the sys and system password, which password should I enter when I open SQL*PLUS?

Comment: You can do `sqlplus / as sysdba` with no username or password - which logs you in as SYS. (But be very careful as SYS, you shouldn't use that routinely; create a new user/schema for yourself and do all your work in that.) There is a lot you need to read, but maybe look at [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/managing-security-for-oracle-database-users.html#GUID-8C779885-01F2-48E0-9612-E33508885B19).

Comment: orcl or orcl.cmh where is says 'service' - not SID